# Python sorted dictionary with equal integer keys

Tags: python

So I have dictionaries with the following structure :

```
my_dict = {"cat":10, "dog":23, "rabbit":52} # And so on
```

Then, I'm sorting them using the integer as key

```
dict_sorted = sorted(my_dict.values(), reverse=True)
```

What I'd like to know is if there's a way to predict how the sorting will behave if I ever get two or more key/value pairs with equal values. Then how will the pairs be sorted ? Alphabetically?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You aren't sorting the dictionary, you're sorting the dictionary values

Comment: You're right thanks. I blundered in the code I chose to copy here. Hopefully @mcsoini understood my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries preserve the key order in newer python versions. If you sort them by value, the key order of identical values will remain the same:

```
my_dict = {"cat":10, "dog":23, "rabbit":52, "elephant": 52}

dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
# out: {'rabbit': 52, 'elephant': 52, 'dog': 23, 'cat': 10}
# => same result as in the original example
```

Most importantly, the keys are not automatically sorted alphabetically, as suggested in the question:

```
my_dict = {"cat":10, "dog":23, "rabbit":52, "x_elephant":52}
dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
# out: {'rabbit': 52, 'x_elephant': 52, 'dog': 23, 'cat': 10}
# => unaffected by the "x"

my_dict = {"x_elephant":52, "cat":10, "dog":23, "rabbit":52}
dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
# out: {'x_elephant': 52, 'rabbit': 52, 'dog': 23, 'cat': 10}
# => follows order of input dict
```

The order is only changed when modifying the order in the original dictionary and is not affected by the alphabetical order.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!